# I deleted my Ubuntu install with windows disk management, and now I can't boot into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

So long story short, I deleted the Ubuntu partitions with windows disk management, and now I can't boot back into Windows.

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows so that I could run some machine learning projects. I created about 20 GB of unused space on my SSD and chose "something else" to install Ubuntu in the unused space. But I figured that I should try to get more space, after reading suggestions online. I tried using `lilo` to fix the MBR, but that didn't seem to work.

There may also be some remnants of previous dual booting attempts, but if they do exist, they never affecting my ability to boot into Windows.

I have one 2 TB hard drive, and 1 256 GB SSD. The SSD contains my Windows 8.1 install.

This is the result of running `boot-repair &`:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YyBHY7mhPJ/

Currently if I reboot my PC, I get this error on a grub screen:

> Minimal BASH like line editing is supported...

`boot-repair` was used via a USB with Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by reinstalling Ubuntu (those deleted Ubuntu partitions wered used for the space). Then after that I rebooted and chose to load Windows. After that I booted from my USB Ubuntu, and used os-uninstaller to correctly remove Ubuntu. Now things work normally, and Windows loads correctly every time.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ubuntu partitions will not uninstall ubuntu.
To restore access to windows you need to fix windows bootloader.

1. Boot from **Windows DVD / USB**
2. When the installation window shows up click **Repair your computer**
3. Click **Troubleshoot** and open **Command prompt**
4. Type `bootrec /fixmbr` and then `bootrec /fixboot` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command
5. Close CMD and reboot

This will remove grub and windows should be able to boot normally.
I think it would be easier for you to repair windows than reinstalling ubuntu and removing it one more time in order to restore access to windows.

[image]